# Java Stream Exception Handling

Tags: java, io, error-handling

I find this piece of Java code really ugly and cumbersome. How can I refactor it to be more clean and easier to read?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(out);
    return out.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

return null;
```

Comment: Don't `catch Exception`! This also catches `RuntimeException` therefore all unchecked exceptions. Catch `RuntimeException` first then rethrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From java 7 on you can use the try-with-resources syntax :

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    workbook.write(out);
    return out.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
```

Which handles the closing of the Stream, and any excptions that may throw, for you.

In earlier versions of Java, you're pretty much stuck with what you have.

***Edit:***

It is worth noting that in case you get an exception on the `close()` method, it is still the original exception that is being thrown. The exception on the `close()` method is then added to that exception as a suppressed exception. You can get at the suppressed exceptions by calling `java.lang.Throwable#getSuppressed`

Comment: But it's worth noting that *"Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect."*

Comment: +1 nice to know Java has the C# equivalent of `using`, which closes/disposes when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

In pre-java 7 (without the try with resources) I find it easier to nest the try-finally in a try-catch:

```
try{

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
        workbook.write(out);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }finally{
        out.close();
    }

}catch(IOException e){
  //handle
}
```

This way there is only 1 point where you need to handle the exception at the cost of an extra indentation level.

Comment: One problem here is that if `workbook.write` throws, then you get a null pointer exception in the finally block which hides the original error.

Comment: @fgb no because out is initialized before the try, and workbook.write can't change it back to null

Comment: Right, sorry. There's still a chance that `out.close` could throw a different exception, but probably not with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

You are catching the exceptions for three purposes:

1. Close the stream to prevent a resource leak,
2. Print a stack trace,
3. Return `null` instead of a byte array.

Of those three consequences, only the first is what I would consider good practice, but even that turns out to be unimportant in the special case of a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html):

> Closing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` has no effect. The methods in this class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating an `IOException`.

So, your whole `finally` clause can be dropped!

Now, we can focus on `catch (Exception e)`.  [Pokémon clauses](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVp-zIONsrs) should be viewed with great suspicion.  What kinds of exceptions might possibly be thrown by `workbook.write(out)`?  `IOException`?  `MalformedWorkbookException`?  You should list exactly what you expect, so as not to swallow exceptions that you didn't intend to handle.

Working with the assumption that `IOException` should be impossible when writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and that the only other remotely probable kind of exception is something like a `MalformedWorkbookException` (which really indicates a programming error in your own code rather than a condition triggered by user-controllable conditions), I would recommend re-thowing the exception. However, since it would be cumbersome to declare that your code `throws IOException` even though it is logically impossible, I suggest smuggling it out by wrapping it in something else.

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    workbook.write(out);
    return out.toByteArray();
} catch (MalformedWorkbookException | IOException e) {
    throw new AssertionError("writing workbook", e);
}
```

Comment: In the last example, could you re-throw the exception as some kind of runtime exception instead? Assertions are often disabled which would result in losing any trace to the original error.

Comment: @fgb I had considered that. But then you would have to declare at least an `IOException` on the method even though it is logically impossible. I suppose you could smuggle out an `IOException` by wrapping it in a `RuntimeException` of some sort, but I opted for simplicity.

Comment: I'd really replace `assert false` by throw new `RuntimeException(e)` as the former provides no exception chaining (which could be a problem with a longer code block). This way you'd get rid of `return null` too, which is good as the method is not supposed to do it and should be declared as such (if possible) and then findbugs and other tools would complain.

Comment: @maaartinus You're right. I've changed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with @bowmore But for someone who is stuck with java 6 and below. Simply create a utility class which will  flush and close output stream for you.

```
public static releaseResource(OutputStream out/Writer out){

    if(out==null)
        return;

    if(out.isClosed())
         return;


    try {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Create two such overloaded method for `OutputStream` and `Writer`. Preferably call this method in finally clause.

You can put it in a utility class or in some base class DAO class and extend it.

This will be some thing like this.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(out);
    return out.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    DBUtil.releaseResource(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the close-method of `ByteArrayOutputStream` does nothing, you can do this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(out);
return out.toByteArray();
```

Since catching all exceptions and swallowing them is a bad practice, I've omitted that code as well.